# Rails 3 - More flexible time_ago_in_words

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my view: `Due <%= time_ago_in_words(todo.due) %>`

But unlike most use cases of time_ago_in_words, I need to support time AGO and time AHEAD. Since a due date can be past due (time ago) and coming up (time ahead), how can I display this conditionally so if it's past due, the above code would output "Due x days ago" and if it's due in the future output "Due in x days"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the looks of it you are using the erb template engine, you can do if conditions in the view logic by obmitting the = sign  So you can do something like this

```
<% if time_ago < Time.now %>
<%= time_ago_in_words(todo.due) %>
<% else %>
<%= time_ahead_in_words(todo.due) %>
<% end %>
```

should give you a idea on what to do.  Though I believe a better practice would be to probably move this to the models portion of your rails app.  I common axiom is Fat Models skinny controllers, but that's more advice then a rule.

**EDIT**

Has Alex mentioned in a comment below this should probably go in a helper method and not in the model part of the app

Comment: _"Fat Models skinny controllers"_ indeed, but in this case that is view logic. If it is to be refactored, it should land in a helper, not the model.

Comment: Also, that first line should probably be `<% if todo.due < Time.now %>`

Comment: now that I think about it, I have to agree with you, and will edit my response.

Comment: Nice article explaining this for German: http://www.railway.at/2013/03/20/distance-of-time-in-words-with-proper-grammar-and-more-flexibility/

Answer (score 1):

In your model have:

```
class Someclass < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_reader :time_diff

def time_diff
    time_difference = 
      if todo.due > Time.new()
        todo - Time.new()
      else
        Time.new() - todo.due
      end
    end
    time_difference.strftime("%I:%M%p")  # This gets returned.  
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= time_in_words(@db_record.time_diff) %>

Where @db_record is a row in the database table for the model in question.
```

Comment: Where are you defining the ```@time_difference``` variable though?

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own helper like this:

```
def time_diff_in_words(from_time)
  # compute days difference from now
  days_delta = (Time.now - from_time) / (24 * 60 * 60)  
  # render text
  days = pluralize(days_delta, 'day')
  days_delta > 0 ? "Due #{days} ago" : "Due in #{days}"       
end
```

Comment: I have kind of a beginner's question, but what is the advantage of writing code in a helper, instead of in the model? Or are you saying write the above code as a "helper method" in the model? Sorry for the confusion here.

Comment: @TrevanHetzel  Rails is based on MVC and one way to keep your view "clean" is to move code and caluculations to helps and other parts of the MVC pattern

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. So in reality I could skip the helper though, and put all my calculation code in the controller?

Comment: well, if I was going to chose I would place it models part of the app.  I would Google "Fat models skinny controllers" there are all kinds of discussions about this

Comment: If you are using this app to learn rails/ruby then I would go for trying to follow best practices, cause it will make your programs and  you better.  On the other hand if this is a product that you are trying to push it maybe best to just leave it how it is and just get it working

Comment: Yeah I'm using this app to learn Rails so I'm trying to go the best practice route. But I also want to get this thing done, so ill probably just leave it for now

Answer (score 0):

If you are do deal with natural language date time parsing, I recommend [chronic gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)

it has many ways of date time parsing

HTH